# Wirtinger's presentation gives that the link group of two disjoint circles is $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, geometric-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

Given two disjoint circles $a$ and $b$ that are projected in a way so that there's a positive and negative $a$-over-$b$ crossing, Wirtinger's presentation gives that the generators $a$ and $b$ commute in the link group, even though the group in actuality is $\mathbb{Z}*\mathbb{Z}$.

Have I made a mistake or have misinterpreted something here, or is it simply that Wirtinger's presentation only works for link diagrams with minimal crossings? I apologize for asking such a short and simple question, but I can't figure this out and it seems like the answer should be clear as day.

Edit: Here's the diagram I'm using, and the relations I got from the two crossings: [two unlinked circles.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ca84Y.png) The only way I see it is that the relations coming from these crossings must be trivial, e.g., $ab=ab$, or $ba=ba$, but I don't see how that could be the case.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I just attached an image of the diagram and the relations. I feel pretty dumb struggling to find where the mistake is, but I honestly have no idea.

Comment: you should have a generator for each arc of your diagram; note that the "b"-circle has 2 arcs, so gives you 2 generators

Comment: @user8268 I completely failed to consider this going from knots to links, thank you!

Comment: Well said. I do feel pretty silly after finding out what the mistake is, but it's cleared up a lot of other confusions I had as well so it was definitely worthwhile to ask!

Answer (score 1):

As user8268 put it, "you should have a generator for each arc of your diagram; note that the "b"-circle has 2 arcs, so gives you 2 generators". Denoting this new generator by $b'$, we have $a,b,b'$ with a single relation $ab=b'a$, meaning $b'=aba^{-1}$ and $a$ and $b$ generate the link group freely.